# simulate agents moving over a grid of different values in python

Tags: python, agent, agent-based-modeling

I'd like to simulate agents that have different interests (e.g. some prefer "red" and some prefer "blue) moving over a grid on which red and blue squares are randomly distributed. At each time point I'd like the agent to compare its current environment to a neighboring environment and move if the neighboring spot better matches its interests. The idea is this looks *somewhat* like a Schelling model, but the environment of grid-squares is static, and the agents (small circles overlaid on the environment on squares) move.

I'm looking for a library that will allow me to model this visually, and show the grid and the agents at different time steps.

Any advice on what I could use to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

This would be trivial in NetLogo.

In Python, you could use [MESA](https://mesa.readthedocs.io/en/master/) or [gridworld](https://github.com/alan-isaac/econpy/tree/master/abm/gridworld).